# Mask values in Python Altair heatmap plots

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite, vega

I'd like to plot a heatmap with masked values using Altair. This can be done via passing a mask array to `seaborn`'s `heatmap` method, but I want to do it using Altair. Thanks!

[image: Desired heatmap with masked values]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Altair, you can apply a mask by removing fro the dataset any data that you don't want to be shown. For example, here is a masked version of the [Simple Heatmap](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/simple_heatmap.html) example from Altair's documentation:

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Compute x^2 + y^2 across a 2D grid
x, y = np.meshgrid(range(-5, 5), range(-5, 5))
z = x ** 2 + y ** 2

# Convert this grid to columnar data expected by Altair
source = pd.DataFrame({'x': x.ravel(),
                       'y': y.ravel(),
                       'z': z.ravel()})

mask = np.random.rand(len(source)) < 0.9

alt.Chart(source.iloc[mask]).mark_rect().encode(
    x='x:O',
    y='y:O',
    color='z:Q'
)
```

[image]

If you want the masking to take place via the chart specification rather than via a preprocessing step, you can similarly filter rows using a [Filter transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/filter.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I see. I guess my reformulated question would be how to manually set `xlim` and `ylim` in a heatmap. I'm asking because I want to use this heatmap in an interactive webapp, and I want different heatmaps to be comparable with regards to `xlim` and `ylim` when the heatmap plot gets updated once the user changes other parameters.

Comment: You can use the `scale.domain` to set the axis domain. Since it's an ordinal scale, you don't set limits, you list the values that you want to appear on the axis; for example `x=alt.X('x:O', scale=alt.Scale(domain=list(range(10))))`